# Sent parameter is not present even if I entered it via Postman

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In the controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("gmao/liaison_alfred")
@CrossOrigin(origins={"*"})
public class LiaisonAlfredGmaoController {
    ...
    @PostMapping("/create_interv_auto_from_alfred_DT_sans_NI")
    public ResponseEntity<ResultatPDD> createIntervAutoFromAlfredDTsansNI(@RequestParam("matriculechauffeur") String matriculechauffeur, @RequestParam("refdemandetransport") String refdemandetransport,
                                                                            @RequestParam("nbkmaller") Double nbkmaller, @RequestParam("nbkmretour") Double nbkmretour, 
                                                                            @RequestParam("moyendetransport") String moyendetransport, @RequestParam("lieudedepart") String lieudedepart) {
        try {
            Intervention i = interventionService.createIntervAutoFromAlfredDTsansNI(matriculechauffeur, refdemandetransport, nbkmaller, nbkmretour, moyendetransport, lieudedepart);
            ResultatPDD resultat = new ResultatPDD();
            resultat.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.toString());
            resultat.setData("Numero intervention : " + i.getInterventionId());
            resultat.setMessage("");
            return new ResponseEntity<ResultatPDD>(resultat, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ResultatPDD resultat = new ResultatPDD();
            resultat.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED.toString());
            resultat.setData(null);
            resultat.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<ResultatPDD>(resultat, HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED);
        }
    }
    
}
```

In Postman I make a POST request with the URL `http://localhost:8080/gmao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/gmao/liaison_alfred/create_interv_auto_from_alfred_DT_sans_NI` :

```
{
    "matriculechauffeur": "xxxx", 
    "refdemandetransport": "DT-202108100950-1",
    "nbkmaller": 12.5,
    "nbkmretour": 12.5,
    "moyendetransport": "vam",
    "lieudedepart": "here"
}
```

But I get error :

```
"exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException",
"message": "Required String parameter 'matriculechauffeur' is not present"
```

So what is wrong ? The `Maven` I am using is `3.6.3`

Comment: @Pheromox, You got an answer but I would like to suggestive you could use the request bean entity because of more than three params passing the request API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are sending it as the body of the request but the backend expects parameters so either change your request to `http://<URL>/?matriculechauffeur=xxx&refdemandetransport=yyyy...` or create a POJO
to hold the object

```
class Voyage {
 private String matriculechauffeur;
 private String refdemandetransport;
 private Double nbkmaller;
 private Double nbkmretour;
 private String moyendetransport;
 private String lieudedepart;

//getter and setters
}
```

and change to

```
public ResponseEntity<ResultatPDD> createIntervAutoFromAlfredDTsansNI(@RequestBody Voyage voyage){
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

these are request param, you have to put them like this

```
url?paramName1=value1&paramName2=value2
```

your example

```
http://localhost:8080/gmao-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/gmao/liaison_alfred/create_interv_auto_from_alfred_DT_sans_NI?matriculechauffeur=xxxx,
```